# can't upload pdf's with wygwam and file manager

Tags: wygwam

I am getting "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." error when uploading pdf's with the file manager via wygwam.

The upload directory is writeable, has all field types allowed and xss filtering is turned off. I can upload other file types just fine.

I can upload pdf's when I use the file manager by itself (not via publish layout). I can also upload pdf's using the same upload directory and the rte field type.

I am running ee 2.6.1 and wygwam 3.1.2.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to upload using the image upload button. When you upload through the link button it might work. It's one of those things :-)

Comment: *facepalm* usability nightmare. thanks though!

Comment: I know, but it's typical for ckeditor, tinymce and the likes, I keep explaining it to end users :-S